# SwiftUI Preview - How to control the size of the 'parent' frame?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, preview

In XCode 14, in the Preview panel for a given SwiftUI view, how can I control the dimensions of the parent my view is a child of ?
None of the four magnifying glass options are what I'm after.

Comment: You can put a `.frame` modifier in the preview code

Comment: You can add a  ".previewLayout(.fixed(width: 300, height: 70))" to the view you want to show in preview

Comment: thank you both, these make sense.   I'm surprised there's no interactive-drag approach.  Clearly it's choosing the parent frame dimensions Somehow. They change on me unpredictably.